# Compare Javascript date with php current date

Tags: javascript, php, date, time, timestamp

I am using the function :

`var date = new Date();`

in javascript.  it gives the following output

`"Sat May 13 2017 22:19:25 GMT+0500 (Pakistan Standard Time)"`

Now I will embed this date in a URL and on server side , I will receive this date.  On server i have a php script , now in this script i want to compare the date received from javascript client side with current php time and check if the difference between date time zone  sent from javascript client side and current php date time zone is greater than 5 minutes or not .

Comment: You should use unix timestamp instead.

Comment: Is time important for comparison?

Comment: i also have date time stamp with zone in millisecond in javascript like this....."1494688862301".....so how can i compare this in php ?

Comment: @YasharAliabasi , yes time is important.....i need to check if 5 minutes have passed since the user clicked on the link......so in php script i need to check if 5 minutes have passed , then i will expire the link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use timestamp comparison.

JS:

```
var timestamp = (new Date()).getTime(); // send this to your php
```

PHP:

```
$timestampFromJs = intval($_GET["ts"]); // just made it up
$ts = time() * 1000; // js timestamp is milliseconds
if($ts - $timestampFromJs > 5000*60) ...
```

UPDATE: If you need timezone safe comparison:

JS:

```
var timestamp = (new Date()).getTime();
```

PHP:

```
$timestampFromJs = intval($_GET["ts"]); // just made it up
$date_utc = new \DateTime("now", new \DateTimeZone("UTC"));
$ts = $date_utc->getTimestamp() * 1000; // js timestamp is milliseconds
if($ts - $timestampFromJs > 5000*60) ...
```

Comment: does this also compare timezones?

Comment: I added timezone check now.

Comment: I always thought that timestamp - seconds for Greenwich. Am I wrong?

Comment: Thats true. GMT = UTC

Comment: The "timezone safe" version **is not timezone safe**. The first version (which uses UTC) is.

Comment: Thats right, getTime method already returns in utc, i forgot it. I ll update the answer